# Content function called twice in Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a Bootstrap Popover which loads a function, like this:

```
var index = 0;

$('#Button').popover({
    html:true,
    placement:'right',
    content:function(){
      index = index +1;
      return index;
    }
});
```

And the HTML is just:

```
<input id="Button" value='popover' type='button'/>
```

So, when I click in the button I should get 1, 2, 3, etc...

However, I'm getting 2,4,6... because it's calling the "content" function twice. Why is that? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d55t7hfa/11/).

Comment: This is a bug, and occurs when you leave the `Title` blank. Add the `Title` and your content function will only be called once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue isn't in your code and comes from bootstrap itself.
See this link:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12563

So, you can just fix it on your side. Set some flag to check if popover is shown.

Comment: Am I not using the last version here (3.3.6)?

Comment: Maybe it's not fix.. I said 'i think' :) Try this solution with flag...

Comment: Hard to believe this is still in BS 5.1.3

Answer (score 2):

Faced the issue and solved it using flag. As it was mentioned, this is bug in Bootstrap code. FYI, the first call is to check whether to make second call. Second call is when the actual rendering happens.

So the logic should be to skip the first call and allow the second call. (and not the other way which results in no content being rendered). For some reason, the first call should not return null. Then the second call is not made. With these, you can look at code below for additional reference.

```js
function popoverHandler(element) {
   
    contentCalled = false; // flag for checking 
    
    element.popover({
        animation: true, 
        container:"body",
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger:"hover",
        "html": true,
        "content": function(){
            var div_id =  "tmp-id-" + $.now();
            return fetchResults(div_id);
        }
    });

    function fetchResults(div_id){
    
        if (!contentCalled) {
            contentCalled = true;
            return " ";
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url         : "getResults",
                type        : "POST",
                data        : <your data>,
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                dataType    : 'json',
                success     : function(response){
                                contentCalled = false;
                                // form htmlOutput
                                $('#'+div_id).html(htmlOutput);
                            }
            });
            return '<div id="'+ div_id +'"><img src="assets/img/loading.gif"/> </div>';
        }
    }
}
```